# Python script call from php not executing properly

Tags: php, python, web, directory-structure

I have made a python script for getting a directory tree. Now I am trying to call this script from php using system().

My Python Script is:

```
import os
from sys import argv

script, start = argv

def list_files(startpath):

    directory = []

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(startpath, topdown=True):

        for named in dirs:
            directory.append(os.path.join(root, named))

        for namef in files:
            directory.append(os.path.join(root, namef))

        return directory

dir = list_files(start)
```

My PHP command is:

```
$var = system('C:\\Python27\\python.exe generate -tree.py F:\\IET', $retval);
echo $var;
echo $retval;
```

The output that I am getting on the browser is the number '2', and when I was doing it a day before the output was coming as the number '1'.

I am new to PHP so couldn't really understand what I am doing wrong here.
Any Guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Is this the complete Python script? In that state it wouldn't produce any output, so in the end you end up with just the returncode of the script.

Comment: @Daniel: Yes this is the complete script. What changes should I make in the Script for it to work?

Comment: You assign the result of the list_files-function to the variable `dir`, but then don't do anything with it. You have to at least print it to get some output. On top of that: what's the filename? What you're doing in PHP is opening the file `generate` with python, having -tree.py and the path as parameters. I guess that's not how it's supposed to be.

Comment: Great, Thanks! It worked for me. Just required a couple of changes.